# Didn't Compound-V make A-Train's heart "stronger"?

Tags: the-boys

A-Train got a [heart transplant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2BOPN5C6-Y) (*"donated"* by Blue Hawk), but the question is, if he was super-abled, why was his heart weak? Did the Compound-V only affect his ability to run and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of Blue Hawk's superpower was superstrength and durability (since he survived the explosion at the Herogasm) but it seems to be temporary (since he died after being dragged on asphalt for a while). So possibly the heart was not durable enough for the amount of stress put on it when A-Train ran.

Since Compound-V gives different powers to different people (possibly DNA dependent?) it seems it didn't give the heart endurance for A-Train's super speed.

Comment: Blue Hawk simply wasn't hit there, otherwise he'd lose powers.

Comment: @Mithoron it doesn't look like supes lose their powers just for being hit, except for the Soldier Boy radioactive beam.

Comment: And I meant what else? Boy killed many supes there and others were depowered. Still, others weren't hit at all. Hawk's durability wasn't temporary, just limited.